# R: Post hoc Test nested ANOVA

Tags: r, nested, anova, posthoc

I did a nested ANOVA for my Data. For that, I tried to orientate on the example on this page:

https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/d_07.html

My Data looks like this:

```
Treatment    Group    Donation
1              1         0
1              1         1.2
1              2         0.3
1              2         0.7
2              1         0.1
2              1         1
2              2         0
2              2         0.7
```

I was able to perform the nested ANOVA as described on the page, but struggle to get the Post hoc test done:

```
library(multcomp)
posthoc = glht(model,
               linfct = mcp(Treatment="Tukey"))
mcs = summary(posthoc,
              test=adjusted("single-step"))
mcs
```

This is the output I get:

```
> library(multcomp)
> posthoc = glht(model,
+                linfct = mcp(Treatment="Tukey"))
Error in `[.data.frame`(mf, nhypo[checknm]) : undefined columns selected
> mcs = summary(posthoc,
+               test=adjusted("single-step"))
Error in summary(posthoc, test = adjusted("single-step")) : 
  object 'posthoc' not found
> mcs
Error: object 'mcs' not found
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. How was `model` created?

Comment: Hi, I will keep that in mind for the next time. I created model using this code:

model = lme(Donation ~ Treatment, random=~1|Session,
            data=Auswertungen_latest,
            method="REML")

Comment: You seem to have `Session` in your model but that doesn't appear in your data. Where does that come from?

Comment: Ah, that's my fault, the header is group, the variable name is session. So its like this: Session <- Data$Group

Comment: No need to keep in mind for next time—you can [edit] the question to include more information

Comment: I wanted to create a reproducible example, but get an error when running the ANOVA: my code:
**model = lme(Donation ~ Treatment, random=~1|Session,
+         data=Auswertungen_latest,
+         method="REML")**
The output:
**> library(nlme)
> model = lme(Donation ~ Treatment, random=~1|Session,
+               +             data=Auswertungen_latest,
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"model = lme(Donation ~ Treatment, random=~1|Session,
              +           data="
>               +           method="REML")
Error: unexpected ')' in "              +             method="REML")"**